# gitlab branch common name - pipeline should be run execpt none branch should not be run

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, rules

I want to run pipeline specific branches in GitLab like the branch names are sprint_100, Sprint-1,SPRINT-202.
How should I give commands in rules?

```
(/^SPRINT_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)||(/^Sprint_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)||(/^Sprint_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)
```

I used this, but it doesn't work. Kindly help me to sort it out this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This `rules` clause should work for your example to run a pipeline only branch names like `sprint_100`, `Sprint-1` or `SPRINT-202`.

The regex will match case-insensitive on branch names starting with 'sprint' followed by either '-' or '_' and an unlimited amount of digits.

I am no regex expert so this regex can likely be improved.

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^SPRINT[-_][0-9]+/i'
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I'd buffered a lot for this task. thank you once again

Comment: [rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^SPRINT[-_][0-9]+/i'
    when: always 
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^SPRINT[-_][0-9]+/i'
    when: never ]- If I had like this , its works but I want the rules like [  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^SPRINT[-_][0-9]+/i'
    when: always 
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^SPRINT[-_][0-9]+/i'
    when: never]-If I gave like this, its doesn't trigger for sprint related branches . can you please help me to sort it out

Comment: @CyrilI Vote and accept are better than thanks. Don't expand your original question, you should open a new one.

Comment: @FranxiHidro fine